# Error when I fill in metadata in excelsheet Document Information Panel

Tags: excel, properties

I am using sharepoint 2010. I have a document library with a contenttype. I have some word, excel and pdf documents inside of it. When I open an existing excel sheet and go to the Document Information Panel I got this error below. It looks like there is something with the column "SCCountryName".

[image]

Here is are the column settings:
[image]

When I enter the metadata the first time it is working. But when I reopen the excelsheet it give me the error.
[image]

This is what I see in SP manager:

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a number of problems related to Document Information Panel.

Cite from [Technet site](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/038f339d-4657-4278-be52-1b6477d1634d/excel-property-gets-lost-when-uploaded-to-sharepoint-document-library?forum=sharepointadminlegacy) with the same Excel problem:

> If there is a property contained in the Excel file that is stored in
>   SharePoint it will still be contained even if that file is
>   subsequently opened from SharePoint or even if downloaded from
>   SharePoint to your hard disk and opened from there.
>
> In fact if the excel file is stored in a document library and that
>   document library has additional columns which for the row of the Excel
>   document have had data added to them, then the downloaded version
>   (from SP) of that Excel file will also contain those columns (with
>   data) as Properties. (With the way non-standard properties are added
>   varying between SPS 2003 and MOSS 2007 ( / SPS 2010)).

Cite from [Technet site](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5ce6b257-bdc6-4f10-8337-789f2fbe1974/word-2010-the-document-information-panel-was-unable-to-load?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious) with a similar issue (the lookup column was the problem):

> Update the Location column’s schema by following the steps below.
>   1. Go to Site Settings -> “Site Columns”
>   2. Click on “Location”, after the page is opened. Don’t modify any settings, click “OK”  to forcibly update the field’s schema.

Same site, different solution:

> I removed the Document content type from the library in question and added it again. 
>   I had to re-check the document set properties in order for column metadata to sync down to the individual documents within the set.

Also, here is a [MSDN link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/243b4852-3f17-4a3a-b6d7-187d65a5f088/error-the-document-information-panel-was-unable-to-load?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy) with numerous solutions for similar problem.

Problem when [changing columns in content type](https://joranmarkx.wordpress.com/2012/02/10/sharepoint-document-information-panel-cannot-create-a-new-blank-form/) with template assigned.

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar issue before. It appears to be the schema synchronization issue between SharePoint and Office applications. Office applications save data in XML format internally and for some reason, it cannot recognize the type of data. I could not find a fix for it and ended up deleting and recreating the column. Please make sure you backup the values from the column before deleting it.

Comment: so there is no fix without deleting/creating libraries or columns?

Comment: I couldn't find anything that help me to solve it. I believe there isn't much help available on the internet. So, it was easier for me to delete and recreate the column.

Comment: I don't want to remove this column because there are a lot of sites/libraries which are using this column. I think the value of the managed metadata field is not correct on the excel file or sp item.